# Is there any way to place a div of specific width and height at a particular point on the screen

Tags: html, css, user-interface, sass

I have a Image that i made which acts as a place holder for some of the elements in my website and i want the elements to be placed exactly there. Like here

[image: The image that i made]

Like in this image how do i place a div of textbox and a button on the board side of the clock exactly there using css and html.

Comment: You are looking for `position`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your can use the `position: absolute` in your css and with the help of the top, right, left and bottom you can set the perfect position for it

for eg

```
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}
```

use this to get the div in center

```
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transfrom : translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

[Use this for more referance](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-positioning-position-absolute-and-relative/)